# PHP webservice for c# application

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I want to create a php webservice server to be used from a C# application.

I want to have a library who autogenerate wsdl file for easy management (That's the reason why I choosed NuSoap).

I tried to use nusoap on PHP5. I have some problems with charset and Content-Type.

Visual Studio gives this error :

`The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://www.xxx.yy'.
There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.
The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.`

`$soap= new soap_server(); 

$soap->xml_encoding = 'utf-8';

$soap->configureWSDL('Bonjour', 'https://www.xxx.yy');

$soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';

$soap->register('bonjour', array('prenom' => 'xsd:string'));`

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");

$soap->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

header('Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8');

function bonjour($prenom)
{
 
    return "Bonjour ".$prenom;
}
 
?>

Does someone knows how to change that to make it compliant and working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found finally a tutorial who worked for me like a charm : http://www.sanity-free.com/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html

Best regards !